# How to fix weird encoding of file while downloading it?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony-2.8

I am trying to download a file from postgresql encoded in base 64. The content of the file seems to be good in the database `bytea` but it is not the same when I download it with PHP:

I am using PHP 5.6 with symfony 2.8. I've tried to decode in base 64 but with no success.

```php
$name = $file->getName();
$content = base64_decode(stream_get_contents($file->getContent()));
$contentType = $file->getContentType();
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set("Cache-Control", "no-cache private");
$response->headers->set("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', $contentType);
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
$response->headers->set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
$response->headers->set('Content-Length: ', strlen($content));
$response->sendHeaders();
$response->setContent($content);
return $response;
```

For this example, I've created a file with notepad++ containing the string "`test`". In the database it is displayed like this "`dGVzdA==`".

When I download the file and I decode it, the content is this "`Ǯ8kθطw`", it should be "`test`".

Comment: Try it without the `$response->headers->set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");` header. What you posted from the DB correctly decodes as expected.

Comment: It remains this: Ǯ8kθطw

Comment: I would start with removing all of the headers except `Content-Disposition` and see if it helps. If it does then start adding the headers back until you find the one that is breaking things. You may also want to `var_dump($contentType);` and see what it contains (it may not be what you expect).

Comment: The content type is: "application/pdf"

Comment: Like I said remove all of the headers except that one.

Comment: If I keep only the header with Content-Disposition, the download file contains: Ǯ8kθطw.

Comment: Is that before or after you decode it? In your original question you said that that was what you got after decoding it. It's not making a lot of sense that that is what you would get before decoding it after it is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PGSQL is converting my file into a hexadecimal value.
It needed to be decoded.
Moreover, there is a "/" at the beginning of the PQGSQL response. It needs to be removed.

Here is my treatment to the content:

```
$content = base64_decode(hex2bin(
    substr(
        stream_get_contents(
            $file->getContent()
        )
    ,1)
));
```